# Backspace String Compare Leetcode Question

Tags: regex, ruby, algorithm, space-complexity

I have a question about the following problem on Leetcode:

Given two strings S and T, return if they are equal when both are typed into empty text editors. # means a backspace character.

Example 1:

```
Input: S = "ab#c", T = "ad#c"
Output: true
Explanation: Both S and T become "ac".
```

Example 2:

```
Input: S = "ab##", T = "c#d#"
Output: true
Explanation: Both S and T become "".
```

Example 3:

```
Input: S = "a##c", T = "#a#c"
Output: true
Explanation: Both S and T become "c".
```

Example 4:

```
Input: S = "a#c", T = "b"
Output: false
Explanation: S becomes "c" while T becomes "b".
Note:
```

1 <= S.length <= 200

1 <= T.length <= 200

S and T only contain lowercase letters and '#' characters.

Follow up:

Can you solve it in O(N) time and O(1) space?

My answer:

```
def backspace_compare(s, t)
   if (s.match?(/[^#[a-z]]/) || t.match?(/[^#[a-z]]/)) || (s.length > 200 || t.length > 200)
    return "fail"
   else
    rubular = /^[\#]+|([^\#](\g<1>)*[\#]+)/
    if s.match?(/#/) && t.match?(/#/)
      s.gsub(rubular, '') == t.gsub(rubular, '')
    else
      new_s = s.match?(/#/) ? s.gsub(rubular, '') : s
      new_t = t.match?(/#/) ? t.gsub(rubular, '') : t
      new_s == new_t
    end
  end
end
```

It works in the terminal and passes the given examples, but when I submit it on leetcode it tells me Time Limit Exceeded. I tried shortening it to:

```
    rubular = /^[\#]+|([^\#](\g<1>)*[\#]+)/
      new_s = s.match?(/#/) ? s.gsub(rubular, '') : s
      new_t = t.match?(/#/) ? t.gsub(rubular, '') : t
      new_s == new_t
```

But also the same error.

So far, I believe my code fulfills the O(n) time, because there are only two ternary operators, which overall is O(n). I'm making 3 assignments and one comparison, so I believe that fulfills the O(1) space complexity.

I have no clue how to proceed beyond this, been working on it for a good 2 hours..

Please point out if there are any mistakes in my code, and how I am able to fix it.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Are there any prerequisites for using regex? Wouldn't it be simpler to parse each character using a loop, and eliminate the ones followed by a `#` sequentially?

Comment: `<1>` Does this mean backreferencing in Ruby? Also, regex match is the time consumer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that with `N` <= 200, your problem is more likely to be linear coefficient, not algorithm complexity.  **O(N)** space is immaterial for this; with only 400 chars total, space is not an issue.  You have six `regex` matches, two of which are redundant.  More important, `regex` is slow processing for such a specific application.

For speed, drop the `regex` stuff and do this one of the straightforward, brute-force ways: run through each string in order, applying the backspaces as appropriate.  For instance, change both the backspace and the preceding letter to spaces.  At the end of your checking, remove all the spaces in making a new string.  Do this with both S and T; compare those for equality.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easiest to start at the end of the string and work towards the beginning:

```
def process(str)
  n = 0
  str.reverse.each_char.with_object('') do |c,s|
    if c == '#'
      n += 1
    else
      n.zero? ? (s << c) : n -= 1
    end
  end.reverse
end
```

```
%w|ab#c ad#c ab## c#d# a##c #a#c a#c b|.each_slice(2) do |s1, s2|
  puts "\"%s\" -> \"%s\", \"%s\" -> \"%s\"  %s" %
    [s1, process(s1), s2, process(s2), (process(s1) == process(s2)).to_s]
end

"ab#c" -> "ac", "ad#c" -> "ac"  true
"ab##" -> "",   "c#d#" -> ""    true
"a##c" -> "c",  "#a#c" -> "c"   true
"a#c"  -> "c",  "b"    -> "b"   false
```

Let's look at a longer string.

```
require 'time'

alpha = ('a'..'z').to_a
  #=> ["a", "b", "c",..., "z"]

s = (10**6).times.with_object('') { |_,s|
  s << (rand < 0.4 ? '#' : alpha.sample) }
  #=> "h####fn#fjn#hw###axm...#zv#f#bhqsgoem#glljo"

s.size
  #=> 1000000
s.count('#')
  #=> 398351
```

and see how long it takes to process.

```
require 'time'

start_time = Time.now
(u = process(s)).size
  #=> 203301 
puts (Time.now - start_time).round(2)
  #=> 0.28 (seconds)

u #=> "ffewuawhfa...qsgoeglljo"
```

As `u` will be missing the 398351 pound signs in `s`, plus an almost equal number of other characters removed by the pound signs, we would expect `u.size` to be about:

```
10**6 - 2 * s.count('#')
  #=> 203298
```

In fact, `u.size #=> 203301`, meaning that, at the end, `203301 - 203298 #=> 3` pound signs were unable to remove a character from `s`.

---

In fact, `process` can be simplified. I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    public boolean backspaceCompare(String s, String t) {
        try {

            Stack<Character> st1 = new Stack<>();
            Stack<Character> st2 = new Stack<>();

            st1 = convertToStack(s);
            st2 = convertToStack(t);

            if (st1.size() != st2.size()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                int length = st1.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    if (st1.peek() != st2.peek())
                        return false;
                    else {
                        st1.pop();
                        st2.pop();
                    }
                    if (st1.isEmpty() && st2.isEmpty())
                        return true;

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }

        return true;

    }

        public Stack<Character> convertToStack(String s){
        Stack<Character> st1 = new Stack<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            if (s.charAt(i) != '#') {
                st1.push(s.charAt(i));
            } else if (st1.empty()) {
                continue;
            } else {
                st1.pop();
            }

        }
        return st1;
    }
}
```